# rotate bodies with box2d and cocos2d in ios

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, box2d

I have objects with fixed rotations that I would like to be able to rotate, either by using two fingers or by simply tapping and applying a rotate transform. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What do you need help with - calculating the angle, setting the angle or both?

Answer (score 3):

override the setRotattion for the sprite, so when you change the rotate property you will also rotate the box2d body

```
-(void)setRotation:(float)rotation {

    float32 b2Angle = -1 * CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(self.rotation);
    spriteBody->SetTransform(b2Position, b2Angle);
}
```

angles in cocos2d and in box2d are handled differently, so you need to transform to radians and multiply by -1 to change direction